# WooCommerce enqueue style on shop page

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-theming, wp-enqueue-scripts

I'm struggling to get a CSS file to load just on WooCommerce shop archive pages only.

Looking at the documentation I know there is a `is_shop()` tag.

So I would have thought

```
function kodr_scripts_styles() {
    if( is_shop() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wc-shop', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/shop-only.css', 'all' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'kodr_scripts_styles' );
```

Would work fine. But the file doesn't load. I know I can use `is_woocommerce()` but I don't want this file loading on all WC pages. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code in your theme function.php:-

EDITED:-

```
function zillion_enqueue_style() {
     if( is_shop() || (is_archive() && is_woocommerce()) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wc-shop-only', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/shop-only.css',array(), 'all' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'zillion_enqueue_style' );
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply. Can you explain how your code is any different from the function I've already tried with?

Comment: you are calling  `wp_enqueue_style()` function but we have to hook it into specific place. `wp_enqueue_scripts()` is the proper hook to use when enqueuing scripts and styles.

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/

Comment: Ok, I already have a hook in place. I just didn't feel the need to add all the code here. Still doesn't work

Comment: can you let me know where you are adding that code? Try adding in function.php

Comment: functions.php. I've edited my original post above to show exactly how I'm calling that function. So it's clearer. I also have many other css and js files enqueued with no issues. just the if( is_shop() does not want to work.

Comment: you can use other conditional tag for check whether it's archive page and woocommmerce also. 
try out the edited code i've posted above